# Neural networks (keras): predicting a periodic output array

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a non-linear multiple regression problem where my target arrays have a length of 256 (for a single sample). These arrays have a periodic structure, since it's actually composed of 16 semi-independent sigmoid-like arrays of equal lengths, whose exact form depend on the inputs (see figure). Although I seem to get good results with some basic RELU activations and a few hidden layers already, I was wondering if e.g. a sine activation function might be appropriate somewhere? How might I implement this in Keras?

EDIT: ok, adding a sine activation was trivial:

```
def sin(x):
  return K.sin(x)
```

However, it doesn't seem to increase performance. I guess because the outputs are not a periodic function of the inputs, but because the whole output array is sort of a static periodic array?

[image: single test sample]

Comment: Interesting plot but! The preds are so close and correct!

Comment: Yes. This was actually with sigmoid activations, it works really well.

Comment: Did you try using a RNN or something like that (since you said that it's having a periodic structure?)